# Can't add virtual environment to Visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I can't seem to work inside of my already existing virtual environments. I am trying to add an interpreter location in the visual studio settings.json

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\timwc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe",
    "python.pythonPath": "D:\\GitProjects\\OrganizationApp\\venv1\\bin\\python"
}
```

However, when I restart VSC and try to change my interpreter (via the Command Palette) it doesn't show up.

Comment: Don't use keys in JSON twice!

Comment: @Timothy Cottrell How did you create this virtual environment? Please try to use only one available pythonpath, and you could refer to it to check your steps of creating a virtual environment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments

Comment: I created the virtual environment with the command 
```python3 -m venv ./venv1```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591164/how-to-set-a-python-interpreter-from-inside-a-existing-virtual-environment-in-vi

Comment: @Jill Cheng That's a link to the same question just worked differently. I realized that two different lines in the settings.json wasn't how it worked thanks to this question. But after fixing that it still didn't change anything.

Comment: @Timothy Cottrell Yes, because the issue that need to be solved for these two threads are the same, it will be better solved when they are linked. Now, let's focus on the latest thread.